# Stream subprocess stdout to jupyter (bash and python)

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, stdout, stderr

I am running some bash scripts inside python. To do so I'm using

```
import subprocess

cm=['bash','/path/to/mybash.sh','-f','flag_val']
p=subprocess.Popen(cm, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
   universal_newlines=True, bufsize=5, close_fds=True)
```

My bash script is writing stdout and stderr to a file, together with all logs.

I'm running this in jupyter, and I'd like to have python waiting for the full bash script to finish before proceeding, but as it is now, it is as if as soon as it passes over `p=...` it simply proceeds and doesn't wait for bash to finish. However, if I don't keep `close_fds=True`, Popen keeps hanging past the time that it takes for the script to finish.

Additionally, I'd also like to see the output from the process inside jupyter *on the fly*, but also keeping bash to write to stdout and stderr.

What do you think I could do to solve these issues?

Comment: Is `-f` meant to be unquoted?

Comment: Just creating a `Popen` object is *supposed* to return immediately. If you want to wait for the process to complete, use `stdout, stderr = p.communicate()`.

Comment: ...that said, if "on the fly" means you want to see content streamed as it completes (with more content continuing to be added as the process writes it), I'm not sure it's a realistic request. I'd need to know a lot more about Jupyter to know if it's possible; you should ask a question only about that, tagged as a Jupyter question, not a generic Python question.

Comment: Can you try to write a narrower, more descriptive title? "Issue with stdout" doesn't do much to tell us what you're trying to ask here. "Stream subprocess stdout to jupyter as it's written", for example, would be clear and descriptive. "subprocess.Popen not letting process finish", likewise.